# Spring cloud stater client not working in existing project

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I was working on a project and then add eureka client dependency in my project but it showing following error.

```
Cannot resolve org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client:unknown
```

Spring version is: 2.3.1

Maven:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But when a create a new project from initializer with eureka client dependency its working fine.
now i am at a lost what to do .

Comment: What does your pom import of spring cloud dependencies look like?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that what's going on here is that for your existing project, you have not included anything in your `pom.xml` stream that defines the version of the `spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client` package you want to use.  Notice the `unknown` at the end of the error message.  But when you create a new project with Initializr, you are getting a `pom.xml` setup that does define a version number for this package.

There is likely some other dependency, possibly `spring-cloud-starter-parent` or `spring-cloud-dependencies`, that you need to add to your `pom.xml` to define version numbers for all the Spring Cloud packages.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that

following setting in pom.xml solves the error

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:
**If you have installed spring boot in your eclipse or you have STS IDE then click on your existing project.
Select spring and then edit starter.
Now spring initializer window will open and here you have to select dependencies as per your need.**
[Select spring and then edit starter screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWcL5.jpg)
[spring initializer window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9NRDY.jpg)